# Session variable being overwritten php

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

ive made a login page which should assign different groups a session ['level'] depending on whether or not they have logged in using the correct details. say the admin logs in he gets session['admin'] session['member'] and session['council'] which all are dependant on his user level from the database.
but when i check the session array i get:
id, username, admin, admin, admin   instead of 
id, username, admin, council, member.
the code i am using for the query is

```
//normal user
$queryN= mysql_query("SELECT * From users where username='$username' and hashed_password ='$dash' AND
level='member' LIMIT 1");
//normal council member
 $queryC = mysql_query("SELECT * From users where username='$username' and hashed_password ='$dash' AND
level='council' LIMIT 1");
//normal admin
$queryA = mysql_query("SELECT * From users where username='$username' and hashed_password ='$dash' AND
level='admin' LIMIT 1");
//Check whether the query was successful or not      
//normal user
if(mysql_num_rows($queryN) == 1)
{session_regenerate_id();
$resultN = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryN);  
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $resultN['id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $resultN['username'];       
$_SESSION['member'] = $resultN['level']; 
session_write_close();
redirect_to("../public/index.php");
}
//admin user
elseif(mysql_num_rows($queryA) == 1){
session_regenerate_id();
$resultA = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryA);   
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $resultA['id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $resultA['username']; 
$_SESSION['admin'] = $resultA['level']; 
$_SESSION['member'] = $resultA['level'];
$_SESSION['council'] = $resultA['level']; 
session_write_close();
redirect_to("../public/staff.php");
}

//council user
elseif(mysql_num_rows($queryC) == 1){
session_regenerate_id();
$resultC = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryC);  
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $resultC['id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $resultC['username'];  
$_SESSION['council'] = $resultC['level']; 
$_SESSION['member'] = $resultC['level'];
session_write_close();
redirect_to("../public/index.php");
}else{
//Login failed
redirect_to("../public/login.php");
}
```

and the functions to check each user credentials are:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = array(); 
    function logged_in() {
        return isset($_SESSION['level']);
    }

    function confirm_logged_in() {
if(!isset ($_SESSION['member']) || (trim($_SESSION['member']) == '')) {
$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'][] = 'You were not Authorised to view that page';
            redirect_to("login.php");
        }
    }
function confirm_login_council() {
if(!isset ($_SESSION['council']) || (trim($_SESSION['council']) == '')) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'][] = 'Sorry but you were not Authorised to view that page';
        redirect_to("login.php");
        }
    }
function confirm_login_admin(){
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']) || (trim($_SESSION['admin']) == '')) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'][] = 'Unfortunately for you; You were not Authorised to view that page';
            redirect_to("login.php");
        }
    }
```

and to check the session array values i used :

```
  foreach($_SESSION as $value){
        echo $value . " | ";
    }
```

Comment: yeh its user_id:1 | username:meloxicam | admin:admin | member:admin | council:admin |

Comment: would this work, if i changed the check user credentials to if if(!isset($_SESSION['member'] && $_SESSION['council'] && $_session['admin']){ then deny and redirect_to($location);} for the function confirm_logged_in()

Comment: sorted this problem out thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the "admin", "member" and "council" session variables to the same value:

```
$_SESSION['admin'] = $resultA['level']; 
$_SESSION['member'] = $resultA['level'];
$_SESSION['council'] = $resultA['level'];
```

Try printing with the key as well to get a clearer picture of what's going on:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
  echo $key, ':', $value , ' | ';
}
```